# Server time off by 1 hour on linux CentOS 6.3 using NTP

Tags: linux, centos, time

So i've setup NTP on my linux CentOS server but my server time is still off by 1 hour. Currently it is `3:53am EST` however, on my linux machine it shows "2:53 AM EST" this is with NTP and using `ntpdate time.nist.gov` and couple other servers trying to sync my server's time but all of this still have my server 1 hour behind the EST time.

Anyone know how to possibly fix this?

Comment: What does `ntptrace` show on the server?  Running `ntpdate` is not the same as using NTP.

Comment: I obviously have it started up and running. In any case simply running `ntptrace` doesn't show work since the server doesn't recognize the command.

Comment: Daylight savings time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you have an up to date `tzdata` package. If you rely on correct time display, then this is a critical package you should keep up to date, as it holds all of the worldwide rules for daylight saving time.

Make sure you set the desired timezone in `/etc/sysconfig/clock` *in addition to* setting up `/etc/localtime`.

Make sure you aren't accidentally using the `US/East-Indiana` zone, which does not observe daylight saving time.

Comment: I found the complete solution here: http://serverfault.com/questions/380561/how-do-i-change-timezone-in-centos-6-2

Answer (score 3):

EST is UTC -5.  EDT is UTC -4.

So, when you say `Currently it is 3:53am EST` you mean `Currently it is 3:53am Eastern`, which is currently EDT.

How exactly did you configure your server's time zone settings?  It's correct in reporting a difference of 5 hours from UTC in EST.  However, since we're currently in daylight savings, so you probably want your server running EDT (and switching between EST and EDT as appropriate).

Comment: I didn't actually configure the timezone settings. But yes, I need it to switch between EST / EDT so it is always synced, any idea how I can do that?